# Image handling, zooming rotating panning and viewport

Tags: graphics, rotating, crop

I am struggling to understand how to properly manipulate graphics. My graphics currently have a rotated viewport, I need a rotated image but a normal rectangular viewport.

Is there a way to adjust the pan, zoom, and rotation of an image without altering the viewport? Or size of the resulting graphic?

To describe a command that would do what I need,

`\addgraphics[width=\linewidth, aspectratio=1.67, zoom=1 ,panx=0.0, pany=0.0, rotation=30]{path/to/file}`

In which the only parameter which takes a unit is the `width`, and `rotation` is always about the center of the viewport. `Panx` and `pany` would be relative from 0 to 1, and `aspectratio` would be a number or default to the original image (pre-rotation). `Zoom` would be from 0 to infinity.

As an example:

The blue box indicates what I want the viewport to be, with anything outside the blue box cropped out, and the graphics need to be properly aligned as indicated by the purple arrow and red line.

[image: rotate]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}~%blank space character
    \includegraphics*[width=0.475\linewidth, angle=30]{example-image-a}%
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

Than may the following code serve as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it also load graphicx
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.475\linewidth,height=44mm}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}~%blank space character
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
path image/.style={path picture={
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
                            \includegraphics[rotate=30]{#1}};}
                   }]
\path [path image=example-image-b] (0,0) rectangle (0.476\linewidth, 44mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
If you like to scale the second image, see, if the following example work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it also load graphicx
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.475\linewidth,height=44mm]{example-image-a}~%blank space character
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
path image/.style={path picture={
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
                            \includegraphics[scale=2, rotate=30]{#1}};}
                   }]
\path [path image=example-image-b] (0,0) rectangle (0.475\linewidth, 44mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without tikz? Im looking for a more generic solution that would work for any picture of any size, without having to manually adjust the bounding box like you did in your path statement. Also I tried adding a scale to the second image and I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: @Bob, well, as seems, you will need to wait to better answer :-). Scaling is done implicitly by defining the width and height of images.

Comment: perhaps there is a way to normalize things by determining the original image size. Any ideas how to figure this information out?

Comment: @Bob, it may be, however so far i don't know. You may looking for solution shown in addendum to my answer (will appear soon)